# How to write a condition to check whether two files are available

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I want to copy files only if both of two specified files are available in the directory.
In this case I want check this via an if condition, but my code below does not work:

```
$File1 = "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\test\1.txt"
$File2 = "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\test\2.txt"
$Ziel = "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\test\a"


if(Test-Path -Path $File1 -and Test-Path -Path $File2)
{
    Move-Item -Path $File1 -Destination $Ziel
    Move-Item -Path $File2 -Destination $Ziel
}
```

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: Please, _edit_ your question and explain what happens. No files are moved? Wrong files are moved? Files moved into wrong directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brackets with condition as below :

```
$File1 = "C:\stack\A.txt"
$File2 = "C:\stack\B.txt"
$Ziel = "C:\stack\copy"

if((Test-Path -Path $File1) -and (Test-Path -Path $File2))
{

    Move-Item -Path $File1 -Destination $Ziel
    Move-Item -Path $File2 -Destination $Ziel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below script block as well.

```
$File1 = "C:\stack\A.txt"
$File2 = "C:\stack\B.txt"
$Ziel = "C:\stack\copy"

if(Test-Path -Path $File1,$File2)
{

    Move-Item -Path $File1 -Destination $Ziel
    Move-Item -Path $File2 -Destination $Ziel
}
```